# Dynamic Redirect from Url.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm building an object using values passed to a Controller through a Url.Action that occurs when the user clicks a button.

```
$.post("@Url.Action("CreateObj", "ObjectController")", {
    value: $value
})
```

In the the method that it calls, I create an object, assign it an id and save the object to the database.

```
public void CreateObj(string value)
{
    Object newObj = Object(value);

    //Magic saving newObj to database

    int id = newObj.objectId; //Saves the object's id to a variable for demo purposes
}
```

Now I want to immediately redirect to the Edit page for this new object where the URL is "./Object/Edit/" + newObj.objectId.

I've tried redirecting within the C# CreateObj method, I've tried passing the objectId through the ViewData so I can redirect in a callback function but I can't find a way to get either to work.

How can I bring the user to the Edit page after creating an Object if I don't know the ID before it is created, and can't access it from the view? Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing an ajax request, your Action should return the Id of the created object, and you should handle the redirection via JS.
So change the return type and value of your Action to:

```
public ActionResult CreateObj(string value) {
    int id = newObj.objectId;
    return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And register a callback function on your post() method to perform the redirection:

```
 $.post("@Url.Action("CreateObj", "Object")", {
                value:"value"
            }).done(function (data) { // data represents the returned id
                //handle success
                window.location.href = `@Url.Action("Edit", "Object")/${data}`;
            }).fail(function () {
                   //Handle failure
            })
```

• Check how $.post() works on [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback in the function where you create the object, trigger this once the object has been created passing to the callback the object id and then inside the callback redirect the user to the new page.

Comment: Could You give an example of this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a callback function in C# and I couldn't get the redirect to work in C#.
I can do both of those in Javascript but I can't access the ID value in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your edit action method looks like this

```
public ActionResult Edit(string value){
   //your magic codes
}
```

you can call this like normal function calls.

```
public void CreateObj(string value)
{
   Object newObj = Object(value);

   //Magic saving newObj to database

   int id = newObj.objectId; //Saves the object's id to a variable for demo purposes
   Edit(id);   // <-- Normal function call
}
```

This will automatically redirect to the edit page.